# Wrong JSON Data being returned within Shopify

Tags: json, ajax, shopify

I've created a Shopify alternative template that returns custom JSON of the products within a collection so that I could store custom metafields in an object to use in jQuery.

I've set up my AJAX GET call and the correct URL, however when I go to test the response of the GET call, instead of returning the custom JSON from the URL provided, it is just returning the standard Shopify collection JSON that you can see from (store_url)/collections/(collection_name).json.

How come it is not returning the response from the URL (store_url)/collections/(collection_name)?view=filter-json

(filter-json is the liquid template that is returning the custom JSON)

```
var coll_url = window.location.href;

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: coll_url,
        data: {
            'view': 'filter-json'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res){
          
            console.log(res);
            console.log(this.url);
          
        },
        error: function(status){
             alert(status);
        }
    })
```

[Image of a (collection_url)?view=filter-json link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0gOV.png)

[Image of returned console log upon action on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HUY0.png)

Comment: If you try this URL in `{shopify-collection-url}?view=filter-json` browser directly, does this return intended JSON ? If no, start from there.

Comment: It does. It returns the intended JSON with all fields filled in correctly and all products within the collection page are present.

Comment: Can you share the URL ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's on a preview theme on our Production side of things. I will post some screenshots below showing the console and the returned JSON from the ?view=filter-json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify in this instance is being smarter-than-thou and is giving you the data they think you want, not the values you actually want.

Whenever you make an AJAX call to a product page expecting a response-type of 'application/json' Shopify will helpfully 'correct' your oversight if you forgot to end your page request with '.js' or '.json' and return the default JSON object for that product.  By setting the `dataType` to `json` in your request, jQuery is helpfully automatically setting these request headers, and so the net result is that all of these helpful behaviours are completely misinterpreting your request.

To access your custom endpoint, you will need to request it without the `json` type to retrieve the contents of your custom page as plain text, then use `JSON.parse` to convert the response data into a usable object.

Good luck!

Comment: Yup it was definitely out-smarting me. Removed the dataType: json so it returned plain text and then parsed the plain text and received the correct Object. Thank you!!

Comment: You are most welcome!  This is an undocumented feature of Shopify that I forget often enough that it bites me almost every time